# Does it matter if you're multiplying a matrix by a matrix rather than a matrix by a vector with the same information?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, rotations

I'm really new to all of this and I'm 13 learning OpenGL. So I was writing a rotation function (3D) for an OpenGL project and I encountered a couple websites that claim that if I multiply the rotation matrix by a vector I would get the correct result. To do this I got the matrix that I was going to rotate and 'translated' its information into a vector. e.g
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 4 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
After that I would multiply the rotation matrix by the vector and it did not work as intended. After this, I simply multiplied the Original Matrix by the Rotation Matrix and it worked as intended. Could I get an explanation on why this would happen when the vector has the same information as the original matrix?

Example:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos(45) & sin(45) & 0\\
0 & -sin(45) & cos(45) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}*
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 4 & 1 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 4 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}*
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & cos(45) & sin(45) & 0\\
0 & -sin(45) & cos(45) & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks.

Edit:
After I finished multiplying the Matrix and the Vector (which I got a vector for the answer) I tried to convert it back to its old matrix form. e.g Matrix[0][0] = Vector[0]

Comment: Oh, thanks! It's fixed now

Comment: It is not clear at all from the question what you want or what is "correct". If you multiply the matrix on the vector you get a vector and if you multiply the matrix by the matrix you get a matrix. Is this your issue?

Comment: Sorry, I should've explained this in the question. After I completed the Matrix * Vector multiplication I tried to put it back into the the form of the original matrix. e.g Matrix[0][0] = Vector[0]

Comment: Are there some typos in your example? For example, in the last $4\times4$ matrix, should the $(3,3)$ element be $\cos(45^\circ)$ rather than $2$? Also, what's the relation between the diagonal matrix in the second product (elements $1$, $4$, $2$, $1$) and the row matrix in the first product (elements $0$, $4$, $1$, $1$)? Should they be the same? And shouldn't that row matrix be a column matrix? (In MathJax you will want a double backslash after each element rather than an ampersand if you want to produce a column matrix.) Finally, what is your rule for putting a vector in matrix form?

Comment: Be careful! The order that you multiply matrices/vectors matters. Specifically, you can't assume that $A*B = B*A$. Intuitively, if you rotate something in one direction, then rotate it the result in another direction, you'd get a different result if you applied the rotations in the opposite order.

Comment: I see that the incorrect matrix element has been corrected, but none of the other errors and requests for clarification have been addressed. I've voted to close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no reason (that I know) why the two computations should give the same answer. In fact, the two computations don’t even give the same **kind** of result: the matrix-times-vector computation gives a vector result, and the matrix-times-matrix one gives a matrix.

Even if you convert your vector result back to a matrix (as in your edited question), there’s still no reason to expect the same results.

Just because two computations involve the same numbers, you shouldn’t expect them to give you the same results. After all, the computations “2+3” and “2*3” both involve 2 and 3, but they obviously don’t give the same result.

To transform points and vectors in OpenGL, you need to multiply them by matrices, not by vectors.

Comment: I forgot to add some information to the post further explaining the question, is there a possibility that you could revise the answer?

Comment: Done. The new info doesn’t much change the answer.

Comment: Since this was the clearest answer i'll accept the answer, thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a diagonal matrix (all the entries are on the diagonal), then you can get those diagonal entries by multiplying by a vector which is all 1s: $$\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & c & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d
\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Let's give these things some names:
$$D = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & b & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & c & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & d
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$w = \begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\1\\1\end{bmatrix}$$
$$v = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$$
And let $M$ be some matrix we would like to apply to (i.e. multiply by) the vector $v$.

So you could directly calculate $M*v$, or since $v = D*w$, you could calculate $M*D*w$. Note that matrix multiplication is associative (i.e. $(M*D)*w = M*(D*w)$). One way to calculate this is to multiply $M*D$, then multiply the result by the vector $w$, which seems to be almost what you're trying to do. Note that when you multiply $M*D$, the result will probably not be a diagonal matrix anymore. Multiplying any matrix by $w$ adds up each row of the matrix to produce a vector, so in short you can recapture the entries of $M*v$ by multiplying $M*D$ and then adding up the rows to form a vector.

On the other hand, you're very close to an important fact about matrices: If you multiply a matrix $M$ by another matrix $N$ then you're in effect multiplying $M$ by each column of $N$.

In other words, if you represented the vector $v = \begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\\d\end{bmatrix}$ as the matrix $C = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & 0 & 0\\
b & 0 & 0 & 0\\
c & 0 & 0 & 0\\
d & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$, then you can calculate $M*v$ by just calculating $M*C$ and taking the first column.

$M*C$ will be exactly the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}
e & 0 & 0 & 0\\
f & 0 & 0 & 0\\
g & 0 & 0 & 0\\
h & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$ where $M*v = \begin{bmatrix}e\\f\\g\\h\end{bmatrix}$.

On the third hand, these are mostly just mathematical amusements. I encourage you to make sure you can get the correct answer out of multiplying the rotation matrix by a vector.